# What is the time complexity of this Factorization program?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics, java

`input: n-bit integer X`

`output: list of prime factors and their multiplicity`

`acc = X`

`for i = 2 ... sqrt( X )`

`--count = 0`

`--while acc % i == 0`

`------acc = acc / i`

`------count = count + 1`

`--if count > 0`

`------print i (count)`

I know that for the worst case, a n-bit integer is 2^n maximum.

So the time complexity for `for i = 2 ... sqrt( X )` is `2^(n/2)-1`

Now I'm really confused with the time complexity of `while acc % i == 0`

For the worst case, let's say that the n-bit number X is a prime. Then the while loop will not be executed at all. How can I define its time-complexity?

How can I find the Big-O of this algorithm? Is iit O(2^n) or O(2^(n/2))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm takes $O(X^{1/2})$ in the worst case, which isn't too bad, but it also takes $\Theta(X^{1/2})$ in the best case. That's because you *always* test divisibility by all numbers up to $X^{1/2}$ even when it is clear that you found all factors of X already.

The loop testing acc % i = 0 is negligible, because X has at most $\log X$ factors.